# Less than operator evaluating for equal values also

Tags: java, operators

experiencing some strange behavior while evaluating a condition which checks if a Float is less than a particular value.

```
    String s = "3700.7777";

    System.out.println(Float.parseFloat(s));

    if(Float.parseFloat(s) < 3700.7777){

        System.out.println("Hi");

    }
```

even though the value of 's' is same as that the value in condition, still the code prints "Hi". 
Since I am using a less than operator, my understanding was that for any value equal to or more than 3700.7777 the condition will fail and it will not print "Hi".

Comment: `3700.7777` is a `double`. Edit: You should avoid testing whether floating point numbers are equal, unless you are extremely careful and know exactly how they work (which you don't, and I don't, and the vast majority of programmers don't).

Comment: "*even though the value of 's' is same as that the value in condition*" => is it?

Comment: check is it working for `if(Float.parseFloat(s) == 3700.7777f)` condition or not??

Answer (score 2):

Change your condition to:

```
if(Float.parseFloat(s) < 3700.7777f) {
                                  ↑
```

See [Primitive Data Types - `float`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) for further information.

Also you might want to know [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Comment: That's after I was validating that I'm a human being to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

Please compare with appending `f` literal, treating that as a float value. Now it is treating that number as `double`

```
if (Float.parseFloat(s) < 3700.7777f) {

            System.out.println("Hi");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Guess I will use Double instead of Float. This solves my problem.

```
    String s = "3700.7777";

    System.out.println(Double.parseDouble(s));

    if(Double.parseDouble(s) < 3700.7777){

        System.out.println("Hi");

    }
```